# PHP blank response for query with returns special characters

Tags: php, mysql

I have an `article` in MySQL which has a `title` column. Now the title column for a specific article `id` has characters `Youâ€™`. When I query this article PHP does not return anything at all and the screen is completely blank. "View source" also doesn't show anything.

Here is the code:

```
static function getArticle($params) 
{
    $id=$params['article_id'];
    $queryv = "SELECT * FROM 'articles WHERE `article_id`='{$id}'";

    $resultv = mysql_query($queryv) or die(json_encode(mysql_error()));
    if (mysql_num_rows($resultv) > 0) 
        {   

            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultv);
            $title=strtoupper($row['article_title']);
            $body=$row['article_body'];
            return(array('article_id'=>$row['article_id'],
                'article_body'=>"<h3 style='width:100%;text-align:center;'>$title</h3>$body",
                'article_title'=>$row['article_title'],
                'article_author'=>$row['article_author'],
                'article_image'=>$row['article_image'],
                'article_share_link'=>$row['article_share_link'],
                'article_author_image'=>$row['article_author_image'],
                ));
        }   
}
```

I'm using `utf8mb4_general_ci` as collation in MySQL. phpmyadmin does return the correct result.

I did search online before posting this question but nobody had this problem of getting absolutely no response.

Comment: It would be nice to edit your question and add the code you've written so far : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are a few places where encoding matters. It's HTML meta tag, real HTML encoding. PHP file encoding, MySQL connection encoding and then database/table/field encoding which you mentioned. There are many possibilities why you fail to find result in MySQL. Good luck with that. ;-)

Comment: PHP error log does not show any result related to my problem actually no entry for todays date exist in php error log.:(

Comment: please **don't** use `mysql_...` functions anymore: _Warning
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
mysqli_query()
PDO::query()_ (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Yes i Normally use PDO prepared stements for MySQL actually this is someone else's code i am just making modificatons

Comment: @aliahmad then this should be the very first thing you should modify: get rid of `mysql_...` functions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

set your php char set to utf-8 by using `ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );` then try to `SELECT CONVERT("Youâ€™",char CHARSET utf8)` it may work

Comment: Problem is getting weirder. Now if i do not include article_body in the $result array the response is fine but if i include article_body same problem and if i change value in the article_title and add article_body in response array again result is OK!